# WebBrowser source from a byte[]

Tags: html, wpf, webbrowser-control, uri, arrays

I have a WPF WebBrowser Component, and I want to set the uri from a byte array of a .htm file,
is that possible, or I have to save the byte stream first?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`WebBrowser.NavigateToStream`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.webbrowser.navigatetostream.aspx) allows you to display a HTML page contained in a stream. If you have a `byte[]`, you could wrap it in a [`MemoryStream`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.memorystream.aspx) to get a `Stream` object.

Alternatively, you could convert the `byte[]` into a String (using [`Encoding.GetString`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/744y86tc.aspx) with the correct encoding) and then show it using [`WebBrowser.NavigateToString`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.webbrowser.navigatetostring.aspx).

Comment: Thanks a lot, I did not know of the method `WebBrowser.NavigateToStream`, very useful and slim ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can convert the byte array into a string representation first, using `System.Text.Encoding.Unicode.GetString(byte[])` (change Unicode to ASCII or UTF8 or however your byte array is encoded). This will give you your URL that you can assign to the WebBrowser control.